# How to restrict specific post types from being read or added by specific user roles (eg. author)?

Tags: custom-post-types, users, user-roles, capabilities

I'm not very clear how to restrict admin area post types access to specific user roles.

In my case, I have some post type such as "suppliers" which I do not want to show to "authors".

By default WP allows authors to browse, add or edit their own content. But I don't want my authors to add a "supplier" or browse entries from other admins.

I've looked into Wordpress code and the codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

there seems to be a parameter in `register_post_type( 'supplier', $args )`, which I tried to define in $args as follows, among of course other variables which I don't think I need to list here since my post type is working fine:

```
     'capabilities'          => array( 'edit_others_posts' ),
     'map_meta_cap'          => true,
```

I haven't fully understood the parameter `"map_meta_cap"` - I assumed that by indicating `'edit_others_posts'` would have sufficed to bar access of 'suppliers' by simple authors (which cannot, in fact, edit other's posts). I tested this and doesn't work. Authors can still see all the "suppliers" content in the admin area and add a supplier as if it was a blog post.

How can I prevent authors (or any other specific user role or users without certain capabilities) to access and add content under specific custom post types I've created?

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the solution to your question, In the `register_post_type` arguments, use the `capability_type` parameter & then grant the specific capabilities to the users. For instance, if you set `'capability_type' => 'supplier'`, grant the `edit_supplier` capability to all administrators only

### More Details

`capabilities` takes an array of the capabilities  in the format `'edit_post' => 'edit_supplier'`

This basically means that wherever the core code was using `edit_post` capability previously, now it will use `edit_supplier` (You'll have to grant `edit_supplier` capability to all the users yourself including the administrators, wordpress doesn't do that for you)

if you didn't provide the capabilities array & `map_meta_cap` is true, then wordpress will generate the default capabilities array from the `capability_type` value provided, like this

```
[edit_post]      => "edit_{$capability_type}"
[read_post]      => "read_{$capability_type}"
[delete_post]        => "delete_{$capability_type}"
[edit_posts]         => "edit_{$capability_type}s"
[edit_others_posts]  => "edit_others_{$capability_type}s"
[publish_posts]      => "publish_{$capability_type}s"
[read_private_posts]     => "read_private_{$capability_type}s"
[delete_posts]           => "delete_{$capability_type}s"
[delete_private_posts]   => "delete_private_{$capability_type}s"
[delete_published_posts] => "delete_published_{$capability_type}s"
[delete_others_posts]    => "delete_others_{$capability_type}s"
[edit_private_posts]     => "edit_private_{$capability_type}s"
[edit_published_posts]   => "edit_published_{$capability_type}s"
```

where `{$capability_type}` is the value you provided. If `map_meta_cap` is false, wordpress will ignore the `capability_type` parameter completely (or say consider it to be 'post' & then use `map_meta_cap`)