# Restrict custom post type view by user role

Tags: custom-post-types, user-roles

I've created a custom post type and created a couple of custom user roles and want to be able to restrict the view of the post type based on the specific roles.

Is there a straightforward way to restrict this?

Comment: Please paste your code. What have you tried already?

Comment: Check out here .may it will help you

[how-to-restrict-specific-post-types-from-being-read-or-added-by-specific-user-roles][1]


  [1]: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71046/how-to-restrict-specific-post-types-from-being-read-or-added-by-specific-user-ro

Answer (score 8):

Every role has capabilities.

Here is a simple contributor to our endeavor: (he just writes and edits)

```
add_role('contributor', 'Contributor', array(
    'read' => true,
    'edit_posts' => true,
    'delete_posts' => false,
));
```

Now he has a new capability (he can edit other peoples posts)

```
function add_capability()
{
    $role = get_role('contributor');
    $role->add_cap('edit_others_posts');
}
add_action('admin_init', 'add_capability');
```

Now to add his new capabilities for our new post type. First lets create the post type:

```
function create_myposttype()
{
    register_post_type(
        'myposttype',
        array(
            'public' => true,
            'capability_type' => 'myposttype',
            'capabilities' => array(
                'publish_posts' => 'publish_myposttypes',
                'edit_posts' => 'edit_myposttypes',
                'edit_others_posts' => 'edit_others_myposttypes',
                'read_private_posts' => 'read_private_myposttypes',
                'edit_post' => 'edit_myposttype',
                'delete_post' => 'delete_myposttype',
                'read_post' => 'read_myposttype',
            ),
        )
    );
}
add_action('init', 'create_myposttype');
```

Post type is created but the contributor has no power on it. Lets give him some juice:

```
function add_capability()
{
    $role = get_role('contributor');
    $role->add_cap('read_myposttype');
    $role->add_cap('edit_myposttypes');
    $role->add_cap('delete_myposttype', false); // to be sure
}
add_action('admin_init', 'add_capability');
```

The read_post and read_* capability assures that the user with that assigned role wont be able to see and access that current area. He will get that generic Wordpress error:

> You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page

And lets make our authors (that default role) are unable to see the **myposttype** posts:

```
function remove_author_capability()
{
    $role = get_role('author');
    $role->add_cap('read_myposttype', false);
}
add_action('admin_init', 'remove_author_capability');
```

Remember to cleanup:

```
function add_roles_on_activation() // add roles on activation
{
    add_role('contributor', 'Contributor', array(
        'read' => true,
        'edit_posts' => true,
        'delete_posts' => false,
    ));
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'add_roles_on_activation');

function add_roles_removal()  // we clean up after ourselves
{
    remove_role('contributor');
}
register_deactivatin_hook(__FILE__, 'add_roles_removal');
```

**Now if you just want to remove stuff from the menu (making them accessible by URL anyway) here is how:**

From the adminbar (that top hovering small menu):

```
function my_edit_adminbar($wp_admin_bar)
{
    if(current_user_can('read_myposttype'))
        $wp_admin_bar->remove_node('new-myposttype');
}
add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'my_edit_adminbar');
```

From the menu:

```
function my_edit_menu()
{
    if(current_user_can('read_myposttype'))
    {
        $slug = 'edit.php?post_type=myposttype';
        remove_menu_page($slug);
    }
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_edit_menu');
```

Answer (score 0):

Well.. I see no code... so I don't know if you created the custom post type yourself, or used a plugin. I'm assuming you created the custom post type in functions.php. In there you can have an if statement to check if the user has certain capabilities.

```
<?php current_user_can( $capability, $args ); ?>
```

It would really help if you could post some code, so that I can give a specific example on how to do this.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can

Comment: This applies to capabilities and not roles. Because the setting is saved to the database wp_user_roles, any function should only run once.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, here is how we can get the current user role.

```
<?php 

// Get the current user id
$user_id = get_current_user_id(); 

// Get the user data based on this id
// returned in an arryay
$user_data = new WP_User( $user_id );


// We could echo out the first role item 
// in the array like this...   
echo $user->roles[0];


// Or we could print the full
// array like this 
print_r($user->roles);

?>
```

Now we could use the above data to construct a simple if statement in the templates. This will vary depending on what your trying to achieve but...

```
<?php 

$user_roll = $user->roles[0];
if($user_roll =="administrator") {

    // Code here will only be run if current
    // user is an admin
}
?>
```

You get the jist of it ;)

Answer (score 0):

When registering a Custom Post Type (CPT) we use the action hook `init` :

`add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_post_type_function', 0 );`

So what we need is putting a user role conditional around this specific CPT registration in two steps :

**1**. Have a function to return the current user role as a string

```
    function my_get_current_user_role() {
     $user = wp_get_current_user();
     $roles = (array)$user->roles;
     return $roles[0];
    }
```

**2**. Then restrict

```
    if(my_get_current_user_role() == 'administrator'){
     add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_post_type_function', 0 );
    }
```